# Send attachments in Mail using PHP

Tags: php, html, file, phpmailer

I want to send file attachments in mail using PHP. Below is code I am using which is working but each time loop gets executed the mails are going in separate attachments.

```
/*Uploading docs Array*/
$otherdoc_name = array($_FILES[ 'otherdoc' ][ 'name' ]);
$otherdocCount = count( $_FILES[ 'otherdoc' ][ 'name' ]);         
// print_r($otherdocCount); exit();
for ( $i = 0; $i < $otherdocCount; $i++ ) {
    //Get the temp file path
    $tmpFilePath = $_FILES[ 'otherdoc' ][ 'tmp_name' ][ $i ];
    $i_names = $_FILES[ 'otherdoc' ][ 'name' ][ $i ];
    $i_sizes = $_FILES[ 'otherdoc' ][ 'size' ][ $i ];
    $i_errors = $_FILES[ 'otherdoc' ][ 'error' ][ $i ];
    $i_tmp_names = $_FILES[ 'otherdoc' ][ 'tmp_name' ][ $i ];
    $i_types = $_FILES[ 'otherdoc' ][ 'type' ][ $i ];
    $exts = pathinfo( $i_names, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
    $msgs = '';

    if ( $i_errors == 0 ) {
        if ( $i_sizes > 0 ) {
            $otherdoc_name[$i] = rand() . '.' . $exts;
            $paths = $folder . $otherdoc_name[$i];
            $uploads = copy( $i_tmp_names, $paths );
            if ( $uploads ) {
                $otherdoc_name[$i] = $otherdoc_name[$i];
                /*Mail Function*/
                if(isset($otherdoc_name))
                {
                    $from_email         = 'my@domain.com'; //from mail, it is mandatory with some hosts
                    $recipient_email    = 'receiver@domain.com'; //recipient email (most cases it is your personal email)

                    //Capture POST data from HTML form and Sanitize them, 
                    $sender_name    = filter_var($_POST["sender_name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //sender name
                    $reply_to_email = filter_var($_POST["sender_email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //sender email used in "reply-to" header
                    $subject        = filter_var($_POST["subject"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //get subject from HTML form
                    $message        = filter_var($_POST["message"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //message

                    /* //don't forget to validate empty fields 
                    if(strlen($sender_name)<1){
                        die('Name is too short or empty!');
                    } 
                    */

                    //Get uploaded file data
                    $file_tmp_name    = $tmpFilePath;
                    $file_name        = $i_names;
                    $file_size        = $i_sizes;
                    $file_type        = $i_types;
                    $file_error       = $i_errors;

                    if($file_error > 0)
                    {
                        die('Upload error or No files uploaded');
                    }
                    //read from the uploaded file & base64_encode content for the mail
                    $handle = fopen($file_tmp_name, "r");
                    $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
                    fclose($handle);
                    $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

                        $boundary = md5("sanwebe");
                        //header
                        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
                        $headers .= "From:".$from_email."\r\n"; 
                        $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$reply_to_email."" . "\r\n";
                        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n"; 

                        //plain text 
                        $body = "--$boundary\r\n";
                        $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
                        $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n"; 
                        $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($message)); 

                        //attachment
                        $body .= "--$boundary\r\n";
                        $body .="Content-Type: $file_type; name=".$file_name."\r\n";
                        $body .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file_name."\r\n";
                        $body .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
                        $body .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000,99999)."\r\n\r\n"; 
                        $body .= $encoded_content; 

                    $sentMail = @mail($recipient_email, $subject, $body, $headers);
                    if($sentMail) //output success or failure messages
                    {       
                        echo 'Thank you for your email';
                    }else{
                        die('Could not send mail.');  
                    }

                }
                /* End Mail Function*/
            } else {
                $otherdoc_name[$i] = '';
            }

        } else {
            $otherdoc_name[$i] = '';
        }

    } else {
        $otherdoc_name[$i] = '';
    }
}
```

I am uploading this files to one folder at present now. Can I send files without uploading directly ?

I want all files should be sent as one mail. Or any other different logic suggestions for me. Please help me out.

Comment: Please check my answer and use phpmailer, it's very easy and provide more security as well. Your email won't be goes into the SPAM folder too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use PHPMailer, that would be really easy to integrate it into your application.

Download the PHPMailer script from here: http://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Extract the archive and copy the `src` folder to a convenient place in your project.

Now, sending emails with attachments incredibly easy:

```
require 'phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'you@example.com';
$email->FromName  = 'Your Name';
$email->Subject   = 'Message Subject';
$email->Body      = $bodytext;
$email->addAddress('destination@example.com');

$email->addAttachment('PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE_HERE');

return $email->send();
```

It's just that one line: `$email->addAttachment();`

Comment: it's working but receiving only one attachment. not multiple.

Comment: You can define multiple as `$email->addAttachment('File1,File2);` etc

Comment: Yes I fixed it by passing multiple files in For Loop. thank you @Darshan Jain

Answer (score 0):

```
    /*Uploading docs Array*/
    $otherdoc_name = array($_FILES[ 'otherdoc' ][ 'name' ]);
    $otherdocCount = count( $_FILES[ 'otherdoc' ][ 'name' ]);         
    $from_email         = 'my@domain.com'; //from mail, it is mandatory with some hosts
                        $recipient_email    = 'receiver@domain.com'; //recipient email (most cases it is your personal email)

                        //Capture POST data from HTML form and Sanitize them, 
                        $sender_name    = filter_var($_POST["sender_name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //sender name
                        $reply_to_email = filter_var($_POST["sender_email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //sender email used in "reply-to" header
                        $subject        = filter_var($_POST["subject"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //get subject from HTML form
                        $message        = filter_var($_POST["message"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //message
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
    // print_r($otherdocCount); exit();
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $otherdocCount; $i++ ) {
        //Get the temp file path
        $tmpFilePath = $_FILES[ 'otherdoc' ][ 'tmp_name' ][ $i ];
        $i_names = $_FILES[ 'otherdoc' ][ 'name' ][ $i ];
        $i_sizes = $_FILES[ 'otherdoc' ][ 'size' ][ $i ];
        $i_errors = $_FILES[ 'otherdoc' ][ 'error' ][ $i ];
        $i_tmp_names = $_FILES[ 'otherdoc' ][ 'tmp_name' ][ $i ];
        $i_types = $_FILES[ 'otherdoc' ][ 'type' ][ $i ];
        $exts = pathinfo( $i_names, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
        $msgs = '';

        if ( $i_errors == 0 ) {
            if ( $i_sizes > 0 ) {
                $otherdoc_name[$i] = rand() . '.' . $exts;
                $paths = $folder . $otherdoc_name[$i];
                $uploads = copy( $i_tmp_names, $paths );
                if ( $uploads ) {
                    $otherdoc_name[$i] = $otherdoc_name[$i];
                    /*Mail Function*/
                    if(isset($otherdoc_name))
                    {


                        /* //don't forget to validate empty fields 
                        if(strlen($sender_name)<1){
                            die('Name is too short or empty!');
                        } 
                        */

                        //Get uploaded file data
                        $file_tmp_name    = $tmpFilePath;
                        $file_name        = $i_names;
                        $file_size        = $i_sizes;
                        $file_type        = $i_types;
                        $file_error       = $i_errors;

                        if($file_error > 0)
                        {
                            die('Upload error or No files uploaded');
                        }
                        //read from the uploaded file & base64_encode content for the mail
                        $handle = fopen($file_tmp_name, "r");
                        $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
                        fclose($handle);
                        $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

                            $boundary = md5("sanwebe");
                            //header

                            $headers .= "From:".$from_email."\r\n"; 
                            $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$reply_to_email."" . "\r\n";
                            $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n"; 

                            //plain text 
                            $body = "--$boundary\r\n";
                            $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
                            $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n"; 
                            $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($message)); 

                            //attachment
                            $body .= "--$boundary\r\n";
                            $body .="Content-Type: $file_type; name=".$file_name."\r\n";
                            $body .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file_name."\r\n";
                            $body .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
                            $body .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000,99999)."\r\n\r\n"; 
                            $body .= $encoded_content; 


                    }
                    /* End Mail Function*/
                } else {
                    $otherdoc_name[$i] = '';
                }

            } else {
                $otherdoc_name[$i] = '';
            }

        } else {
            $otherdoc_name[$i] = '';
        }
    }

$sentMail = @mail($recipient_email, $subject, $body, $headers);
                        if($sentMail) //output success or failure messages
                        {       
                            echo 'Thank you for your email';
                        }else{
                            die('Could not send mail.');  
                        }
```

You can simply take the mail function outside the loop? Try above code. Please ignore syntax errors as I have not tested it. But you can follow the logic.

### Update

Working script in core PHP to send multiple attachments in single mail.

```
<?php
/** Mail with attachment */
function mail_attachment($filename, $path, $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto, $bcc, $subject, $message){    
    $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$uid}x"; 

    $header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
    $header .= "Bcc: ".$bcc."\r\n";
    $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$mime_boundary."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$mime_boundary."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= nl2br($message)."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$mime_boundary."\r\n";

    foreach($filename as $k=>$v){

        $file = $path.$v;
        $file_size = filesize($file);
        $handle = fopen($file, "r");
        $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
        fclose($handle);
        $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

        $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$v."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
        $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$v."\"\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= "--".$mime_boundary."--"."\r\n";
    } 

    if (mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header)) {
        //echo "mail send ... OK"; // or use booleans here
        return true;
    } else {
        //echo "mail send ... ERROR!";
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks but not working same problem attachments are going separately with different mail, not in one mail.

Comment: Check my update. I have added a working script, you can modify the script according to your need. It will give you the clear idea. @AkashM

Comment: This code is unsafe; Refer to the PHP docs on how to handle file uploads safely.